# How to use strtotime function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used `PHP` code as follows to print `MYSQL` date value on html page. I want to do the same formatting using `Jquery` . How to do it?

in PHP

```
echo date("j F Y, g:i A",strtotime($add->added_date))
```

J query alert

```
var date = retdata[i].added_date; // date comes as 2016-02-27 06:14:15
alert (''); //formatting here??? i want as 2016 Feb 27 06:14 AM
```

Comment: you want to apply same format with jquery or you want to display already php formatted date with js? if second, you can inject php code into your js line.

Comment: You can send formatted date from server no need to format date twice in PHP and JavaScript;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to manipulate and parse dates in javascript.

If your date comes as a string, you should be able to parse in your format so (remember to include moment.js in your document and be careful with the format, the following is just an example and you should look for the time format of your date am,pm,24h):

```
var parsedDate = moment("2016-02-27 06:14:15","YYYY-MM-DD H m s");
console.log(parsedDate.format("YYYY MMM DD hh:mm A")); // 2016 Feb 27 06:14 AM
```

Comment: yes! it's right answer. rather than strugling with how to convert, which manipulations to do, I prefer to use momentjs. it's more elegant and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert(date)` since you defined `date` already.

You do not need to format the timestamp since you already formatted it using PHP. The only question (we cannot tell from the little bit of information you provided) is how you are passing the information to JavaScript/jQuery via the `retdata` array. This should show the "2016-02-27 06:14:15" (or whatever date/time information) from `var date` within the modal window if it is/was properly passed or defined before being called by `alert()`.